# Export data from a webpage

Tags: java, android, html

I want to export some data mostly strings and images from a html webpage to the java\android program that I want to write, can anyone give me a hint about that?

Comment: You can look for [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It's an `html` parser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTTPClient Library of Apache.
On this site [Link](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html) you can find examples for it.
And if you want to go that way, remember to download the apache logging jar as well, as it is a dependency of the HttpClient Library